# Is there a word for the leather that covers a dead person's face?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for the leather that covers a dead person's face? I am pretty sure there was a word for that, but I can't remember what it was.

Comment: What leather? We don't usually have them in Britain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard of leather specifically, or even of just the face being covered, but a general term for something that a corpse is wrapped in is a [**shroud**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shroud):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1** : burial garment : [WINDING-SHEET](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/winding-sheet), [CEREMENT](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cerement)
>
> *winding-sheet*
> : a sheet in which a corpse is wrapped
>
> *cerement*
> : a shroud for the dead
> *especially* : [CERECLOTH](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cerecloth) —usually used in plural
>
> *cerecloth*
> : cloth treated with melted wax or gummy matter and formerly used especially for wrapping a dead body

Answer (score 1):

Never heard of leather either...

There are death masks made of wax or plaster....

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_mask#:~:text=A%20death%20mask%20is%20a,used%20for%20creation%20of%20portraits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_mask#:%7E:text=A%20death%20mask%20is%20a,used%20for%20creation%20of%20portraits).

But I think it is more likely  that the word you are looking for is not for bodies' heads  but babies'...  a cawl

> A caul or cowl is a piece of membrane that can cover a newborn's head and face.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caul